# Mainline DHT unexpected message from other nodes

Tags: dht

It looks like part of some kind of flood prevention mechanism but i am not sure.

Query sent:

> `d1:t2:021:y1:q1:q4:ping1:ad2:id20:ê¹L®<ê½¸.å»…°H$W5ee`

Query in hex:

> `64313A74323A3032313A79313A71313A71343A70696E67313A6164323A696432303AEAB9034C7FAE3C8DEABDB82EE5BB85B0482457356565`

Recieved message:

> `A\0\u0006Ÿ4\u001f’t\0\0\0\0\0\u0010\0\0j{\0\0`

Received message in hex:

> `4100069F341F927400000000001000006A7B0000`

Can someone please tell me what is this message? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you verified with wireshark that that those strings match the UDP packet contents that you receive? Otherwise it might be an issue with using socket APIs incorrectly.

Comment: @the8472, Yes, i just did that. Message contents are matching exactly. Problem is not appearing constantly, so i had issues with reproducing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently all defined DHT messages are bencoded dictionaries, thus should start with a `d`, so this clearly is not a DHT message.

But multiple services can operate on a DHT port as long as the protocols can be disambiguated. The looks like it might be a [uTP SYN](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0029.html) and the remote peer is simply guessing your node also speaks bittorrent-over-uTP.
If you don't intend to support then you can just drop that packet and consider the actual DHT response as still pending at that point.

A sidenote, your query is not valid bencoding. BEP 3 specifies that [dictionary keys must be sorted](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html#bencoding).

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts! I greatly appreciate it.